# I can not add google translator on my joomla 2.5

Tags: php, joomla, google-translate

i am trying to add google translator on my joomla 2.5 but once i locate the google code in index.php and then transfer it back to the original position from CUTEFTP 8.3.3, it won't work and sometimes it does not open my website till, i change it to the original index.

Comment: how do you paste that code?

Comment: when i open my index.php is much different than others that i watched from youtube. mine gives some text that much different than others .     it gives something like this(i open it with ultrasedit)
if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php')) {
 include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/defines.php';
}

if (!defined('_JDEFINES')) {
 define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));
 require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/defines.php';
}

require_once JPATH_BASE.'/includes/framework.php';

// Mark afterLoad in the profiler.
JDEBUG ? $_PROFILER

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to use the free GTranslate module. There are versions for Joomla 1.0, 1.5 and 2.5/3.x. For details see:

https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/gtranslate

Comment: i will try it as fast as i can get into my administrator.i don't know why i can't get into my website administrator. when i type my website name and / the rest ( it doesn't even load the page) and it says restricted access

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean you use the Google Translator Widget [1] on your Joomla site and it used to work, but suddenly stopped working after you transfer your code through CUTEFTP then deploy?
If it used to work then the problem lies with how the code is transferred through CUTEFTP. However you also mentioned you have trouble accessing even the Joomla Admin page, which means this is an issue that should be taken up with the Joomla community at [2] instead of here at Stackoverflow.

[1] https://translate.google.com/manager/website/?hl=en
[2] https://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=797712